# Does iPad support the file:// protocol?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, file-uri

I want to know whether the iPad supports the file:// protocol. I want to pack an application with a HTML file. When running that, the app will load the HTML in its webview.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have you had a look at phonegap?

Comment: I did see the phonegap site but in that they haven't mentioned about ipad anywhere. I did think that both are iOS then it means it should support.But need to confirm whether it works or not

Comment: That's good. So can we call the objective c methods by using javascript then?

Comment: Yes phonegap allows you to call your custom objective c listener class  if you can't find an existing phonegap method that suites your needs. Just be careful calling custom methods as you would need to write the corresponding methods for other platforms if you ever wanted to support them... hope this makes sense

Comment: Here are is the wiki on writing plugins: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins